# Control rows to keep with distinct in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Here I have a data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a=c("A", "A", "B"), b=c(1, 0, 1))
df2 %>% 
  distinct(a, .keep_all=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
  a b
1 A 1
2 B 1
```

But I would like to control which row is kept with a condition. E.g. `distinct(a)` but keep the row when b==0. That is I want to keep the other row with A.

Comment: You sure after arrange the problem is resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the `tibble` before using `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- data.frame(a=c("A", "A", "B"), b=c(1, 0, 1))
df2 %>% 
  arrange(a, b) %>%
  distinct(a, .keep_all=TRUE)
#   a b
# 1 A 0
# 2 B 1
```

Comment: If you add one more row A 199, will this keep this line in the output ? (Since 199 is unique in columns b)

Comment: @Wen-Ben If the users want to have 199 if there are any, and then 0, and then 1, what I can think about is to convert the column `b` to factor, and set the levels to be c(199, 0, 1). After that, use `arrange` and `distinct`.

Comment: @ www. I have also seen when column a is a factor then distinct does not work at all. I might post a new question tomorrow.

Comment: @David Whether column a is a factor or a character should not affect the `distinct` function. Please leave me a message when you posted your new question. I would be interested in learning more.

Comment: @ www. Okay thanks. I will post it tomorrow and write a message here. I have an example where it does not work.

Comment: @ www. I have posted a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705659/distinct-in-dplyr-does-not-work-sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

You may need build a self-define function for check all `duplicated` , the we need combine both check from columns a and b

```
dupf=function(x){

     return(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE))

 }
df2 %>% dplyr::mutate(ft=!(dupf(a)&dupf(b)))%>%filter(ft)
  a b   ft
1 A 0 TRUE
2 B 1 TRUE
```