# Distinct in dplyr does not work (sometimes)

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have the following data frame which I have obtained from a count. I have used `dput` to make the data frame available and then edited the data frame so there is a duplicate of `A`.

```
df <- structure(list(Procedure = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "A", "C", "D", "-1"), 
                                         class = "factor"), n = c(10717L, 4412L, 2058L, 1480L)), 
              class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("Procedure", "n"))

print(df)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Procedure     n
  <fct>     <int>
1 D         10717
2 A          4412
3 A          2058
4 C          1480
```

Now I would like to take distinct on Procedure and only keep the first `A`.

```
df %>% 
  distinct(Procedure, .keep_all=TRUE)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Procedure     n
  <fct>     <int>
1 D         10717
2 A          4412
3 A          2058
4 C          1480
```

It does not work. Strange...

Comment: Try to convert `Procedure` to `character` ;)

Comment: @ well yes, but I cannot find any place in the documentation that it should behave differently with factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we print the `Procedure` column, we can see that there are duplicated levels for `a`, which is problematic for the `distinct` function.

```
df$Procedure
[1] D A A C
Levels: A A C D -1
Warning message:
In print.factor(x) : duplicated level [2] in factor
```

One way to fix is to drop the factor levels. We can use `factor` function to achieve this. Another way is to convert the `Procedure` column to character.

```
df <- structure(list(Procedure = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "A", "C", "D", "-1"), 
                                           class = "factor"), n = c(10717L, 4412L, 2058L, 1480L)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("Procedure", "n"))


library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Procedure = factor(Procedure)) %>%
  distinct(Procedure, .keep_all=TRUE)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Procedure     n
#   <fct>     <int>
# 1 D         10717
# 2 A          4412
# 3 C          1480
```

Comment: @ www. I still get this error ``Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: factor level [2] is duplicated.``.  It stops after ``mutate``.

Comment: I just tried to run the code in the datacamp.com environment and got the same error message.

Comment: @David Perhaps the `tibble` package is outdated. Please update it to the most recent version on cran (2.0.1) and try again.

Comment: @ www. Well I thought it would work because ``dplyr`` was not updated but still the same error.

Comment: @David Datacamp is in R 3.4.2, while I am using R 3.5.2. Please try to update the R to the most current version.

Comment: @ www. Well that must be it, my R version is 3.4.1, but I cannot update my R version, because it is a work computer and I have to use the "webshop" for applications.

Answer (score -2):

You have duplicated value in a label parameter .Label = c("A", "A", "C", "D", "-1"). That is an issue. Btw your way of initializing of a tibble seems to be very strange (i do not know exactly your goal but still)

Why not use

```
df <- tibble(
    Procedure = c("D", "A", "A", "C"),
    n = c(10717L, 4412L, 2058L, 1480L)
)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You are just stating the problem. Also, what you see there is the `dput` of the data frame. Not a way to initialize it

Comment: No. I disagree that this is not an answer. The problem is an incorrect initialization of factor with duplicate values of labels. That's why distinct does not work properly.

Comment: This is indeed the answer, although you might also want to include the result of `distinct` to keep the downvoters at bay.

Comment: No, It is not an initialization of a data frame. It is a resulting data frame *obtained from a count* (as per the OP) where the `Procedure` column is set as a factor variable. Therefore, in order for `distinct` to work the specific column needs to be set as a character first.

Comment: @Sotos "obtained from a count" is very vague; the column in question is a badly formed factor variable. `distinct` has no problems with factors, but it assumes they have to obey the rules.

Comment: @ Hong Ooi: ``dplyr`` has a ``count`` which is a shortcut for ``group_by`` and then ``summarise( n=n())``

Comment: @HongOoi, not that vague. Count is the actual `count` function of `dplyr` (If you see the resulting column is named `n`). I agree the question is not clear, but I still think that the initialization of the data frame is not the problem here.

Comment: @Sotos Yes, I'm aware that there is a `count` function in dplyr. "Count" is also a regular English word. Ultimately, the problem is still that the factor variable is badly formed, whether because dplyr's `count` has a bug (possible but unlikely) or OP mangled the data somehow.

Comment: I think @cat_zeppelin pointed out why `distinct` is not working (because of duplicated factor level in `Procedure` column), but re-initialize the data frame is not a practical solution as this may be an intermediate product from a pipeline that David cannot go back and modify it. I would suggest drop factor level before `distinct`: `df %>% 
  mutate(Procedure = factor(Procedure)) %>%
  distinct(Procedure, .keep_all=TRUE)`. By doing this, the `distinct` function will work. If cat_zeppelin is willing to edit his post to incude my code, I will consider it as a valid answer and upvote it.

Comment: @HongOoi, exactly. But It will not be solved by taking the result of the 'count' and manually constructing a data frame. Well, It will work, but it does not scale and is definitely not recommended

Comment: @ everyone: To be fair I have made a count and then edited the ``dput``, because I wanted to ask another question. It is not possible to get a ``count`` like my ``dput``. But I was looking to find a example for ``distinct`` and then I edited the ``dput`` then saw that it did not work so I made a question.

Comment: @David This code will work `df %>% mutate(Procedure = factor(Procedure)) %>% distinct(Procedure, .keep_all=TRUE)`, which drops the factor level in the `Procedure` column. Or just convert `Procedure` to character. You cannot expect `distince` works properly when there are duplicated factor level.

Comment: @ www. I get this error when I run your code: ``Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: factor level [2] is duplicated``

Comment: @David Please see my post. I start with the code you provided and I did not receive the error message you posted.

Comment: @ www. Hi, I was rereading the back and forth and I must admit I have just understood your explanation now.